# 3D Scene Renderer for Python

Tags: python, 3d, scene

I'm looking for an easy to use 3D scene renderer for Python. All I'm looking for is to be able to:

- Load a 3D scene model
- Render it using an orthographic camera
- Export the image so I can perform analysis

So far the software I've found is either too low-level (like basic OpenGL bindings) or too complex (like Ogre). Any advice?

Comment: The scene needs to consist of a just a handful of different types of simple objects like blocks, cylinders and spheres (representing buildings and trees). Any file format would do.

Comment: What about just generating input for some stand-alone command-line renderer (eg: Povray) and then reading in its output?

Comment: That's a good idea, perhaps I'm thinking too complex. :)

Comment: What's wrong with Ogre anyway? You don't have to use the full complexity.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Really depends exactly what you want to accomplish. How complex is your scene? What sort of render quality are you after? Do you need real-time animation, or are rendered stills good enough?

First-rate, full game engines (have been used for commercial games)

- Panda3d http://www.panda3d.org/
- PyOgre http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/PyOgre
- Pyrr (Irrlicht wrapper)

Less popular 3d engines, new or beta: YMMV.

- OpenSceneGraph http://www.openscenegraph.org/projects/osg
- Spyre http://pduel.sourceforge.net/spyre/spyre.spyre-module.html
- PySoy http://www.pysoy.org/
- Soya http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Soya/0.11.2
- PyCrystal http://www.crystalspace3d.org/main/PyCrystal
- Horde3d http://www.horde3d.org/
- VTK (Visualization Tool Kit) http://www.vtk.org/

Low-level OpenGL interfaces - more control, more for you to do yourself

- PyOpenGL http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/
- Pyglet http://www.pyglet.org/
- Zoe http://www.alcyone.com/software/zoe/

Non-realtime interfaces

- cgkit http://cgkit.sourceforge.net/documentation.html (Renderman, Maya)
- Blender http://www.blender3d.org/
- POVray wrapper http://code.activestate.com/recipes/205451/

Comment: Is this answer still accurate, 30 years later?

Comment: An Alternative can be PCL (Point Cloud Library); But I did not work with it my self

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend Panda3D. It supports everything in the list, and is "high-level" too. The manual describes how to achieve everything needed.